# Finding current region with lat long in offline mode

Tags: ios, gps

I am currently working on an app which requires the current region in which the user is in.The worst part is app is completely off line.

My logic :

1.Take a screen shot of the city draw squares on that.

1. Store square 4 points (lat long values taken with respect to map) in DB.
2. With the lat long values got from gps i can easily find out lat lont belongs to what reason.

I am just wondering if anybody can suggest me better idea to work my app offline.

Thank you in advance ..

Comment: Will the device have free view to sky?

Comment: ok, with GPS you get the geo coordinate; what do you define with the term  "region": Country name? self defined regions?

Comment: @AlexWien region means cities what client means in our app..

Comment: please be more specific: do you want to display a map of that city, or only get the name of the nearest city?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find you have problems getting a location if you have no network access. iOS uses assisted-GPS, which allows the device to both lock onto GPS satellites much faster than it might otherwise take, and also pull in other data from the network to quickly determine location.

Without network access you may not get a location reported back at all, especially if the app was being used indoors (vanilla GPS reception is typically very bad without line of sight). If you *do* get a location it may take several minutes for an accurate enough reading to be provided.

Comment: The app is being built for non-network area like mining is done. Client want it to work in offline mode at any cost.

Comment: To be brutally honest with you, you may well find location performance to be *so* poor without network that you'll have to consider using an external GPS antenna/receiver. They do exist for iPhones and iPads, since this isn't a totally uncommon problem (for example, if you're using an iPad for aerospace).

Comment: @lxt this is so wrong: iphone has one of the best, if not the best at all, consumer recieivers. no external gps will deliver a bette result. without network gps start up time is slower (30s). he states that he will have free view to sky, so no need forvan external antenna like in closed airplanes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the RouteMe library which is based on OpenStreetMap. this allows to download map data in advance.

If you want to work with screenshots (from a legal source) then you use the Helmert transformation to transform between gps and picture-pixel coordinazes.
you need at least 3 points in the picture-map for which you now the lat,lon coordinates.